# Python - How to call in sequence of next player in LIST

Tags: python, list

I'm having some issue how to actually calling the next player from LIST by sequence.

Basically, I need to check from p_record LIST that contains the player names.

```
    def main():

    attempts = 0
    white = 0
    wrong = 0
    score = 0
    black = 0 
    game = True    
    p_record = []
    whiteblack = []
    colors = ['B', 'R', 'Y', 'O', 'G', 'P']
    color_code = random.sample(colors, 4)         
    print ("HIDDEN CODE", color_code)
    num = int(input('Please enter number of players: '))
    for i in range(num):
             names = input('Please enter a name: ')
             p_record.append([names, 0, 0])
             print(p_record)
             print(len(p_record))
    print(names + ",", "make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: ")          
    player_guess = input("").upper()               
    for i in range(len(player_guess)):                     
             if player_guess[i] == color_code[i]:
                      black += 1
                      score += 5
                      whiteblack.append("B")
             if player_guess[i] != color_code[i] and player_guess[i] in color_code:
                      white += 1
                      score += 1
                      whiteblack.append("W")

             else:
                      whiteblack.append("")

    color_codeString = ''.join(color_code)                      
    whiteblackString = ''.join(whiteblack)              
    print("Result", whiteblackString)
    print("Current player:", names, "Current Score:", score % score)                                  
    print("Current player:", names, "Updated Score:", score)
    if(player_guess == color_codeString):
             print("Winner: ", p_record)            


main()
```

Here is the outcome that I wanted.

> Enter number of players: 3
>
> Enter player's name: alan
>
> Enter player's name: betty
>
> Enter player's name: cindy   Alan, make a guess of 4 colors from
>   RGBYOP: BYOP
>
> Result WWB
>
> Current Player:  Alan Current Score:  0
>
> Current Player: Alan Updated Score:  7
>
> Betty, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: BYOR
>
> Result WB
>
> Current Player:  Betty Current Score:  0 Current Player:  Betty
>   Updated Score:  0
>
> Cindy, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: BYPG
>
> Result WWWB   Current Player:  Cindy Current Score:  0 Current Player:
>   Cindy Updated Score:  1
>
> Alan, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: BPGY
>
> Result BBBB   Current Player:  Alan Current Score:  7 Current Player: 
>   Alan Updated Score:  22
>
> Correct guess!
>
> [['Alan', 22, 2], ['Betty', 0, 0], ['Cindy', 1, 0]] Winner: ['Alan',
>   22, 2]

Comment: If you do not actually want those empty lines, try code-formatting the desired output.

Comment: I cant, it gave me an error "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”

Comment: That is still applicable now. So, use the formatting and add some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over your `p_record` list. Here's a simple example.

```
p_record = [
    ['Alan', 0, 0],
    ['Betty', 0, 0],
    ['Cindy', 0, 0],
]

game = True
while game:
    for player in p_record:
        print(player)
        player[1] += 1
        if player[1] > 3:
            game = False
            break
```

**output**

```
['Alan', 0, 0]
['Betty', 0, 0]
['Cindy', 0, 0]
['Alan', 1, 0]
['Betty', 1, 0]
['Cindy', 1, 0]
['Alan', 2, 0]
['Betty', 2, 0]
['Cindy', 2, 0]
['Alan', 3, 0]
```

You may also find the examples here helpful: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).